# Add new line after every period in txt file in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've done some research online and cant find a solution to my problem.

So I got a .txt file, the problem is that all the text is in one line. I would like to make a new line after every period (.). With linux terminal.

I.e

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation >ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Should be like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.

Comment: Do you want a blank line or a newline? What's up with the `>`? Your before and after contain different amounts of text.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I would like the next sentence to start on a new line. Sorry, ignore the text, its only a Lorem Ipsum copypaste

Comment: Do you want the space after the period  removed ? Or is something like `sed 's/[.]/&\n\n/g'` what you like?

Answer (score 2):

Perl is (still) very handy for this kind of text manipulation:

```sh
perl -pe 's/\.\s+/.\n\n/g' file.txt
```

Comment: I agree, though not sure if the *"Windows Subsystem for Linux"* thing includes Perl?

Comment: WSL has you install a linux distribution, so perl should be there.

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu in WSL on a Windows 10 VM running in Parallels on my Mac. Whew, it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: For my part, I have studiously, skilfully and successfully avoided Windows and that's why I didn't know Perl was in there. But now I know that and a little more too, so I thank you!

Comment: @MarkSetchell : Plus, there are several Perl implementations running natively on Windows, and one for the Cygwin environment.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

echo "text1.  test test text2. " | sed s/'.'/'.\n'/g | sed 's/^ *//'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr` to split sentences on token=`.`:

```
lines=$(echo "adde.ede dded.aefaefe.aefeaf" | tr "." "\n")
#lines=$(cat somefile.txt | tr "." "\n")
```

And then print the lines with newline:

```
#for l in $lines;do echo "$l."; echo; done  # causes word splitting, put quotes around $lines
for l in "$lines";do echo "$l."; echo; done
```

output:

```
adde
ede dded
aefaefe
aefeaf.
```

Comment: That'll add a linebreak/period after every single word because of unquoted expansion of `$lines`. Try an input example like `Sentence with multiple words.` to check.

Comment: Why use any process substitution?  Just do `tr . \\n < input-file | sed 's/$/./'` to replace each `.` with a newline and then put a `.` at the end of each line. (Effectively reinserting the periods that were deleted when they were converted to a newline.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell When the inputfile already has newlines, you add additional dots.